# End Session after Blocking user and manually expire access token

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I'm running an `ASP web API` application with `Angular 5` front end application, I'm using `ASP Identity` for Authentication.

Now my app has a feature of ***blocking users*** , but as I'm using access tokens, I can't find a way to log users out as soon as they are blocked unless I use a bad practice (mentioned in the last lines of the question).

There is a ***Verify*** method in the back end API application, it checks the access token if it is valid on each service call from the Angular app , of course this access token is not changed when the user is blocked, so the user keeps accessing until his access token expires.

what is the best practice to overcome this?

the bad practice I'm using:

```
  Verify() {
     var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
     var user = db.users.Where(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();

     if(!user.isActive) { return Ok("Blocked")}
     else {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { return Ok("Authorized"); }
        else return Ok("Not Authorized");
        }
  }
```

but the function Verify is called many times, so searching the database each time is not a good solution.

--> To clarify the signing out in the Angular app, it first clears the access token from local storage, then redirects to sign in page, so it has nothing to do with the Web Api

--> Please tell me if any point needs to be clarified in my question

Comment: _"the function Verify is called many times, so searching the database each time is not a good solution"_ you could put blocked users in an in-memory cache to cut down on DB calls. If they are blocked temporarily, you can set the expiry on the cache to the blocking period.

Comment: you may also store some kind of _JWT Token Id_ right inside your token, and store black-list of this tokens in memory.

Comment: How long is a block generally enforced ? Permanently ? The time frame could influence the answer to your question.

Comment: @stuartd The function Verify should not be calling the database at all I think, and the blocking depends on the admin, he changes the user status as he likes, so no blocking period, I mean for now at least

Comment: @cl0ud Blocking depends on the admin, he changes the user status as he likes, so no blocking period

Comment: If the admin is writing the blocked status directly to the database then I don't see any way you can avoid querying the database to find the status.

Comment: @PatrickMorgan if its real time and must be instant once the admin blocks I dont think theres a way of avoiding having to check the db on every api call. What is perhaps an option is using websockets to restrict the Angular application once the admin blocks. eg , The admin blocks , the angular app is notified of this via a message pushed down from the api to the app , the app then boots the user off and on login you check if the user is blocked , this could potentially solve your problem. Let me know if that is something you consider viable.

Comment: @PatrickMorgan let us know what you decide to go with !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If avoiding db calls is absolutely necessary I would push the responsibility of booting the user from the application to the Angular side. Please see my proposed flow using web sockets below.

1. The admin blocks the user , the api gets hit with block instruction for a user. The 
   api marks the user as blocked in the database and pushes a message down to the angular application via websockets (I would use 
   signal R for your setup) that contains the userId.
2. The angular application checks if the userId sent from the api is the one that belongs 
   to the current users session (session storage perhaps). If that is the case boot the 
   user out by clearing hes token and signing him out.
3. If the user tries to log in again simply move the check to see if a user is blocked to your login method and he/she will no longer be able to log in again.

This is putting all your eggs in one basket by relying on your socket connection to boot users but it cancels out having the responsibility on the api to check on every call and will reduce the chatter to your db.